# C# BouncyCastle SSL/TLS Алгоритм действий Handshake

Tags: c#, ssl, tls, bouncycastle

Всем привет!
Я новичок в этом никогда не реализовывал, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Использую библиотеку BouncyCastle хочу реализовать шифрование канала с помощью SSL/TLS. Но не могу понять с чего надо начинать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: С выбора алгоритма шифрования.

Comment: Хорошо, я выбрал дальше какие действия?

Comment: Реализовать на C# незашифрованное соединение, чтобы работало. Затем предпринять попытки его зашифровать, и если не получится, то написать здесь, что именно не получилось и показать код. Для справки, можно попутно читать спецификации протокола TLS. Вы ведь хотите свое вместо TLS написать с использованием сокетов, так? Если же хотите использовать уже готовые решения, то WebSocket и HTTPS к вашим услугам.

Comment: В том то и дело что я написал изначально что использую библиотеку BouncyCastle, уних там есть готовое TLS и мне хотелось бы посмотреть пример если кто то работал с ихней бибилиотекой в этом направлении.

Comment: BouncyCastle не про передачу данных, а про шифрование данных. Берете данные, шифруете с помощью BC и передаете дальше. Сама библиотека ничего никуда не передает. Еще раз, чем вас HTTPS не устраивает? Что именно вы и куда передаете? Зачем вам шифрование? Пример показать не сложно, непонятно только пример чего.

Comment: [Вот кстати пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6721587/12888024)

Comment: Я нигде не писал что хочу отправить данные через BC )). Просто уних в библиотеке есть множество методов например:1. **Tls**, 2.**PskTls** 3. **MockTls** 4. **MockSrpTls** 5. **MockPsk**.. и т.д  это немного путает, какой из методов выбрать. А так меня всё устраивает. Я передаю данные с сервера клиенту и обратно. А обязательно использовать WebSocket? я например использую TcpClient и TcpListener. И ещё вопрос если я например использую шаблон Web API 2 ASP.NET возможно ли там применить TLS, либо самому надо прописывать сервере?

Comment: Если вы используете Web API, зачем вообще вам `TcpClient`? Если можно использовать HTTPS и стандартный `HttpClient`, который все зашифрует сам при работе по `https://`. по поыоду ASP.NET - вам надо смотреть документацию. Насколько мне известно, TLS там можно настроить без особых проблем, для этого понадобится только сертификат.

Comment: Насчёт TcpClient просто учусь смотрю как работает, вот и пришла в голову мысль что для Web API не надо TcpClient т.к там уже всё настроенно. Вы говорити HttpClient сам всё зашифрует. А как же передавать сертификат от клиента к серверу и наоборот, при процессе рукопожатии? спасибо за полезную инфу!

Comment: `HttpClient` все это сделает за вас. Просто настройте и используйте HTTPS.